# Dockerfile distroless unable to locate custom module

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, distroless

I have two folders:

scripts/

- main.py

source/

- memory.py

My dockerfile ( I am using example from https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/blob/main/examples/python3-requirements/Dockerfile)
:

```
FROM debian:11-slim AS build

RUN mkdir scripts
COPY source source
COPY scripts/main.py scripts/main.py

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-suggests --no-install-recommends --yes python3-venv gcc libpython3-dev && \
    python3 -m venv /venv && \
    /venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3-debian11
COPY --from=build /venv /venv
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV PYTHONPATH /source

ENTRYPOINT ["/venv/bin/python3", "scripts/main.py"]
```

I get the following:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/app/scripts/main.py", line 5, in

```
import memory as mm
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'memory'

my main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import memory as mm

...
```

Comment: In the build stage you tell python to install `venv` in `/venv`. So I'm guessing somewhere in its internal files python will register this association in order to recall it when needed. Then you throw everything away and start a new build stage and all you copy is the `/venv` directory. You have to ask yourself: in this new stage, how would python know where to locate `venv`? Try to do everything in 1 stage for now and see that it works. Then you can try to optimize

Comment: The last line knows where to call venv and python, right? @Mihai

Comment: you might be right, but that doesn't fix your issue, does it? did you try my suggestion instead?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I’ve tried a lot of things like setting PYTHONPATH manually but to no avail. Not sure what is missing.